# Google.API.Translate.Translator.Translate method causing exception

Tags: c#

I am using google GoogleTranslateAPI version v2.0.50727 dll. when I'm executing the following code it is giving the exception:

> **Translate failed!**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Text = "This is a string to translate"; 

    Console.WriteLine("Before Translation:{0}", Text);

    Text = Google.API.Translate.Translator.Translate  
    (Text,Google.API.Translate.Language.English,
     Google.API.Translate.Language.French);

    Console.WriteLine("Before Translation:{0}", Text);

    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google Translate API for .Net v0.2 uses [Google Translate API v1](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/getting_started.html) which is now deprecated.

Check out the [overview](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) of Google Translate API:

> Important: Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service only, and the number of requests your application can make per day is limited. As of December 1, 2011, Google Translate API v1 is no longer available; it was officially deprecated on May 26, 2011.

So, I guess you have to switch to Google Translate API for .NET v0.3. In this case you have to acquire an API Key for your application from google

Answer (score 0):

Google has made the Translation API a paid service and the number of requests your application can make per day, free of charge is limited. I suggest you visit this link and do check out the samples here.[Google Translation API .Net samples](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/20120316-1.1.4457-beta/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.1.4457-beta.samples.zip)